# Can a Data Request Form be Routed to another SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint site set-up, I have another site that is for the entire company. If someone is requesting data they will fill out a data request form from site A, is there a way to take site A's data form redirect it to site B? What I am trying to do is, take our internal data form and when a particular project is selected it will redirect to that project site. Can this be done? Thanks for any help.